# Best way to associate metadata with a class type

Tags: c#, types

I want to build a little entity framework, where I need some information from an entity class type e.g DbType(SQL, MongoDB), DbName, TableName, IdProperty. I thought about:

- static methods (needs reflection with hard coded strings to invoke from type)
- instance methods (need to instantiate the type)
- app.config (not directly in the class)
- class attribute (needs reflection)
- store in database (to get an entity from the DB I need to get data from the DB first, seems not so nice)

What is the best and fastest method to get metadata for an entity type?

Comment: base class that supports it?

Comment: But the metadata is different for each model. How should a base class help? I only have the type not a class instance.

Comment: Well, you have to do something. having a common base class is one approach. Everything else you seem to have discounted.

Comment: But I don't understand how a base class should store Informations like database or tablename for each sub class? I think I'll use class attributes, cause there are used in many libraries for storing metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are what you want for this. Its a broad topic so I'll just link to the MSDN documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx

> Attributes provide a powerful method of associating metadata, or
>   declarative information, with code (assemblies, types, methods,
>   properties, and so forth).

Essentially you can create an attribute class (or use an existing one) and then apply it to your classes and then when you want to you can query that metadata for whatever information you've stored in them.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind mixing the metadata with your code, I would go with attributes on the classes and the fields.